# How to Create a Sitemap.xml file for my links specified in the Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, xml, plugins, sitemap

I want to create a `sitemap.xml` for all the links specified through the javascript file.

The online sitemap generators aren't crawling through my website properly and generating the `sitemap.xml` file with the 100s of links generated through the JS file(by using the data coming from the JSONs), and so is the case with `'sitemap-xml plugin'` for grunt.

Can somebody suggest me if there is any easy way to implement this?

Comment: If your executing javascript in the browser you won't be able to do this. What is your server setup?

Comment: @Stewart: Its a single server. There should be some way to dynamically generate an XML file within the javascript file itself, right?

Comment: Does your javascript execute on the client or the server?

Comment: It executes on the client

Comment: I'm glad you have a solution for this problem however I think for this question to be of value to anyone having the same issue you might want to provide a little more detail. What is your motivation for wanting to generate a sitemap.xml? How does that sitemap relate to your frontend application? Why not use your server to generate it on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a custom grunt task that did the trick. Only that, I had to rerun the task everytime I added new links. But still this works for me! Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Hey, can you post that grant code here for others referrance?